# How to set Session-Parameter after JSF Navigation-Rule in a portlet environment with the to-view-id

Tags: jsf-2, portlet, portal

We are currently facing one problem in our portlet-environment using JSF2.

The application is creating dynamic portal-pages for the actual user session...think of it as Eclipse editor-views where the user can edit entities. So for now I call the dynamic-views editors :-)

The problem we are facing now, is following. The user navigates to a editor and works on the portlet(s). The displayed views in each portlet change over time of course. Now he wants to have a look on another entity which is displayed in another editor. **But when he navigates back to the first editor, the state of portlets changes back to the default views.**

In the portlet-world each portlet each portlet gets the view it should display via a parameter which is stored in the PortletSession and I can easily change that parameter as well. I know that this parameter is causing the trouble because when the changes the editors, the portlets will always check this parameter to decide which view to show.

```
request.getPortletSession().setAttribute("com.ibm.faces.portlet.page.view", "/MyPage.xhtml");
```

My idea was, to somehow add a callback to each JSF-navigation which will set this parameter to the view the navigation is going to display (possibly including view-params).
Is it possible to have a standard callback? If not, would be possible to execute some kind of EL in the navigation-rule that will set this parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *somehow add a callback to each JSF-navigation*

You could perform the job in a custom [`ConfigurableNavigationHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ConfigurableNavigationHandler.html). Here's a kickoff example:

```
public class MyNavigationHandler extends ConfigurableNavigationHandler {

    private NavigationHandler parent;

    public MyNavigationHandler(NavigationHandler parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleNavigation(FacesContext context, String from, String outcome) {

        // TODO: Do your job here. 

        // Keep the following line untouched. This will perform the actual navigation.
        parent.handleNavigation(context, from, outcome);        
    }

    @Override
    public NavigationCase getNavigationCase(FacesContext context, String fromAction, String outcome) {
        return (parent instanceof ConfigurableNavigationHandler)
            ? ((ConfigurableNavigationHandler) parent).getNavigationCase(context, fromAction, outcome)
            : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Set<NavigationCase>> getNavigationCases() {
        return (parent instanceof ConfigurableNavigationHandler)
            ? ((ConfigurableNavigationHandler) parent).getNavigationCases()
            : null;
    }

}
```

To get it to run, register it as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<application>
    <navigation-handler>com.example.MyNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
</application>
```

Comment: Works smoothly. After the handleNavigation was executed the ViewRoot is updated and I can set the parameter. Currently it looks like we have to handle all navigations via form-submits since I couldnt see a way to use the NavigationHandler for h:link as well (but it makes sense since this will result in a plain html-link).

Thanks for your hint.

Comment: You can handle `<h:link>` by a custom `ViewHandler` (just extend `ViewHandlerWrapper`).

Comment: would it make sense to use a PhaseListener that runs when the page is rendered? Then it might work as well for plain Links.

Comment: You can't figure out in there if a navigation is performed or not. It might be just a postback to the same view. Or if you actually don't need to hook on "every navigation" but rather on "every postback" then a `PhaseListener` would indeed be a better place. Do the job in afterphase of `INVOKE_APPLICATION` then.

Comment: The PhaseListener works for perfectly. Since I just need to update the portlet to the view that is displayed I used the Render_Response-Phase which sets the view to the current portlet-session every time. So this way I we can now use plain links again.